# How can I localize cpEditUrl?

Tags: localization

I use the following code to link to the CP from the front end:

```
{% if entry.isEditable() %}
  <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}">Edit entry</a>
{% endif %}
```

What do I have to add to link to the correct locale as it always jumps to the global locale instead of the current one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
 {% if entry.isEditable() %}
    <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}/{{ craft.locale }}">Edit entry</a>
 {% endif %}
```